# Iterating array of object in angular ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have an object like this

```
var questions= [{ QuestionId:"1",
                  QuestionName:"loreum ispum?",
                  Answers: [{option:"A",Score:10},
                            {option:"B",Score:10}                       
                            ]
                 },
                 { QuestionId:"2",
                   QuestionName:"loreum ispum?",
                    Answers: [{option:"A",Score:10},
                              {option:"B",Score:10}                       
                             ]
                 }]
```

Iterating through ng-repeat

```
 <ul ng-repeat="question in vm.questions">
   <div class="">{{question.QuestionName}}</div>
   <input type="text" ng-model="getdetails.QuestionId" ng-value="question.QuestionId" style="display:none"/>
   <li ng-repeat="answer in question.Answers track by $index">
      <input type="radio" name="questionId_[$index]">" ng-model="getdetails.Score" ng-value="answer.Score" />
   </li>
   <button class="btn btn-success no-broder-radius" ng-click="change(getdetails)">Submit</button>
 </ul>
```

and clicking on submit button I need to get the Question id and selected input value.

Controller :

```
     $scope.getdetails={};
    $scope.change=function(getDetails) {
     // I am getting only input radio value not getting question id
}
```

I am getting only input radio value not getting question id

Comment: can you make plunker or codepen please?

Comment: where did 'getdetails' come from?

Comment: @omid.n getdetails is a $scope variable..

Comment: @PraveenMP Apparently, you have to pass 'question' instead of 'getDetails'

Answer (score 0):

If `getDetails` is a `$scope` variable then you can directly access it in your controller, you don't need to pass it from view.

Try this:

```
 <ul ng-repeat="question in vm.questions">
   <div class="">{{question.QuestionName}}</div>
   <input type="text" ng-model="getDetails.QuestionId" ng-value="question.QuestionId" style="display:none"></input>
   <li ng-repeat="answer in question.Answers track by $index">
     <input type="radio" name="questionId_[$index]">" ng-model="getdetails.Score" ng-value="answer.Score" />
   </li>
   <button class="btn btn-success no-broder-radius" ng-click="change(question)">Submit</button>
</ul>
```

Now in change function, you will have access to the full object.